# django/python custom data encryption

Tags: python, django

I have some string, lets say `string = "abcd4345.345rg"` and I am looking for simple python module which will allow me to encrypt/descrypt it using some key (AES for example).

I am writing this question because I can't find any module in django for this - I found only hashing functions. I need one small module with function like `encrypt(data,key)/decrypt(data,key)` nothing more.

Comment: Do you need a symmetric algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify if you need symmetric or asymetric algorithms. Anyway, you can check python crypto docs (hmac can be a good asymmetic/public-key option):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/crypto.html

And PyCrypto for AES:

https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/